# Javascript calculation including null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get my variables to equal an object value (this part works) but if the object is non existent I want to value of the variable to equal 0.

```
    function calc(){

   var d_r1_qte = document.autoSumForm.d_r1_qte.value;  // this work for getting the value is the object exist 
  var d_r1_unitprice = document.autoSumForm.d_r1_unitprice.value || 0; // this doesn't work for setting the variable to 0 if the document object doesn't exist
  document.autoSumForm.d_r1_price.value = d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice; 

  var d_r2_qte = document.autoSumForm.d_r2_qte.value;
  var d_r2_unitprice = document.autoSumForm.d_r2_unitprice.value;
  document.autoSumForm.d_r2_price.value = d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice;

document.autoSumForm.rtotal.value = ((d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice) + (d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice)); // the goal is to get this value even if there are non existent object in the equation

}
```

I thought it would be simple but I have been trying to make this work for 2 days now. I'm not used to JavaScript.

Any help would be a revelation. I'm so curious to know how to write it properly.

Thank you in advance!

I tried:

```
    var d_r1_qte = document.autoSumForm.d_r1_qte.value ? document.autoSumForm.d_r1_qte.value : 0;
  var d_r1_unitprice = document.autoSumForm.d_r1_unitprice.value ? document.autoSumForm.d_r1_unitprice.value : 0;
  document.autoSumForm.d_r1_price.value = d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice;

  var d_r2_qte = document.autoSumForm.d_r2_qte.value ? document.autoSumForm.d_r2_qte.value : 0;
  var d_r2_unitprice = document.autoSumForm.d_r2_unitprice.value ? document.autoSumForm.d_r2_unitprice.value : 0;
  document.autoSumForm.d_r2_price.value = d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice;

document.autoSumForm.rtotal.value = ((d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice) + (d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice));
```

and :

```
      var d_r1_qte = document.autoSumForm?.d_r1_qte?.value || 0;
  var d_r1_unitprice = document.autoSumForm?.d_r1_unitprice?.value || 0;
  document.autoSumForm.d_r1_price.value = d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice;

  var d_r2_qte = document.autoSumForm?.d_r2_qte?.value || 0;
  var d_r2_unitprice = document.autoSumForm?.d_r2_unitprice?.value || 0;
  document.autoSumForm.d_r2_price.value = d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice;

document.autoSumForm.rtotal.value = ((d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice) + (d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice));
```

But

```
document.autoSumForm.rtotal.value = ((d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice) + (d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice));
```

Still won't calculate until the object are created.

The object are created with this php:

```
<?php

//fetch.php;

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=fmr", "fmr", "creationfmr2020");
$connect->exec("set names utf8");

if(isset($_POST['a1']))
{
 $query = "
 SELECT DISTINCT aname FROM articles 
 WHERE aname LIKE '%".trim($_POST["a1"])."%'
 ";

 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

 $statement->execute();

 $result = $statement->fetchAll();

 $output = '';

 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '
  <li class="list-group-item contsearcha1">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="gsearcha1" style="color:#333;text-decoration:none;">'.$row["aname"].'</a>
  </li>
  ';
 }

 echo $output;
}

if(isset($_POST['a1s']))
{
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM articles
 WHERE aname = '".trim($_POST["a1s"])."' 
 LIMIT 1
 ";

 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

 $statement->execute();

 $result = $statement->fetchAll();

 $output = '
 
 ';

 foreach($result as $row)
 { 

  $output .= '



                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="apad" style="width:4%">
                            <label>Qte</label>
                             <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="d_r1_qte" value="" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();">
                          </div>
                          <div class="apad" style="width:85%" >
                            <label>Description</label>
                             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="d_r1_adesc" value="'.$row["adesc"].'" >
                          </div>
                          <div class="apad" style="width:5%">
                            <td><label>Unit.</label>
                             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="d_r1_unitprice" value="'.$row["unitprice"].'" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();">
                          </div>
                          <div class="apad" style="width:6%">
                            <label>Prix</label>
                             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="d_r1_price">

                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                       

                            
                            

  ';
 }
 $output .= '';

 echo $output;
}

?>
```

This seems to work:

```
d_r1_qte = document.autoSumForm?.d_r1_qte?.value ?? 0;
d_r1_unitprice = document.autoSumForm?.d_r1_unitprice?.value ?? 0;
  document.autoSumForm.d_r1_price.value = d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice;

d_r2_qte = document.autoSumForm?.d_r2_qte?.value ?? 0;
d_r2_unitprice = document.autoSumForm?.d_r2_unitprice?.value ?? 0;
  document.autoSumForm.d_r2_price.value = d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice;

document.autoSumForm.rtotal.value = ((d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice) + (d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice));
```

But

```
document.autoSumForm.rtotal.value = ((d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice) + (d_r2_qte * d_r2_unitprice));
```

Still doesn't calculate until both item are created.
https://creationfmr.com/fmr-test.mp4

Comment: Have you tried using `if` statements to check for the existence of the object?

Comment: I tried with isset and typeof but with no luck.

Comment: Can you post an example of the object you're looking to check for as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator (`?.`). It will short-circuit and return `undefined` in case you try to access a property on `null` or `undefined`.

```
var d_r1_unitprice = document.autoSumForm?.d_r1_unitprice?.value || 0;
```

Comment: I tried this:
   var d_r1_unitprice = document.autoSumForm?.d_r1_unitprice?.value || 0;
  var d_r1_unitprice = document.autoSumForm?.d_r1_unitprice?.value || 0;
  document.autoSumForm.d_r1_price.value = d_r1_qte * d_r1_unitprice;

but the 3rd line which calculated both variables doesn's work anymore. Any idea? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You probably want to use the nullish coalescing operator (`??`) instead of or (`||`), unless you're taking advantage of the empty string's falsiness.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think it makes much of a difference here. Yes, empty strings probably should be defaulted to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide examples of what and how is not working for you, so I will provide a general answer, with the hope that it covers your situation as well.

```
foo || 0
```

will yield foo in general and 0 if `foo` is falsy.

Let's see your line:

var d_r1_unitprice = document.autoSumForm.d_r1_unitprice.value || 0;

Assuming that both `document` and `document.autoSumForm` exists, this will work. `document` exists in your browser, therefore `document.autoSumForm` does not exist. As a result, whatever member of a nonexistent object you intend to refer will yield an error for you, which is the problem. For example this would work:

```
var d_r1_unitprice = (document.autoSumForm && document.autoSumForm.d_r1_unitprice.value) || 0;
```

because it checks the existence of your object AND its member. But it's ugly. Let's make a general, nicer approach:

```
function getInnerMemberOrDefault(obj, keyChain) {
    for (let key of keyChain) {
        if (!obj[key]) return 0;
        obj = obj[key];
    }
    return obj || 0;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
getInnerMemberOrDefault(document, ['autoSumForm', 'd_r1_unitprice.value']);
```